# Scroll to permalink anchor when coming to website from link

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a website where content is loaded from markdown then rendered.
The rendered content has headers (h1, h2 etc.) with automatically generated anchors.

If I click on the anchor, it scrolls nicely to have it on top - but if I copy the URL and paste it to another tab, page loads but doesn't scroll.

Sample URL: `localhost/articles/16/gq#one-endpoint-one-request-multiple-resources`

I would love to show some code, but there's nothing I can show - scrolling to anchors is Nuxt's default behavior as seen here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/packages/vue-app/template/router.scrollBehavior.js

Here's my code for debugging, checking if hash and the element to scroll to exists.

```
mounted()
{
    console.log(this.$route.hash)

    console.log(document.querySelector(this.$route.hash))
},
```

.. clearly, they both do:

[image: yes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-page-transition-and-anchor-handler :)